# What am I missing with Redux-Saga?

Tags: typescript, redux, react-router, redux-saga

I've been trying to integrate Redux-Saga into my React/Redux app for a while now and there is some key part of this that I'm missing (as it doesn't want to work).

My understanding of how this is supposed to work is as follows:

1. In the `rootSaga` function, I fork off a "Watcher" which watches for a particular action to occur.
2. When the watcher sees the action, it calls the handler for that action and calls the appropriate success/fail action when completed.
3. I should use `put` or `call` to dispatch an action for the watcher to see.

Below is the closest I've come (conceptually) to getting it to work (code hastily anonymized, so please forgive any typos).

My sagas.ts file:

```typescript
import { all, call, fork, put, takeLatest} from 'redux-saga/effects';
import { fromJS } from 'immutable';
import AppRedux, { IAction } from 'app/containers/App/reducers';

const fetchData = async (id: string, name: string): Promise<any> => {
    console.log('calling fetchData');
    const resource = `someurl?id=${id}`;
    const data = await((await fetch(resource)).json()); // request(resource);
    console.log('returning fetchData');
    return fromJS({
        id: id,
        name,
        data,
    });
};

const callFetchData = function* callFetchData(action: IAction) {
    console.log('calling callFetchData*');
    try {
        const result = yield call(fetchData, action.id, action.name);
        yield put({
            type: AppRedux.Action.DATA_FETCHED,
            result,
        });
    } catch (error) {
        yield put({
            type: AppRedux.Action.FETCH_FAILED,
            error,
        });
    }
    console.log('exiting callFetchData*');
};

const watchCallFetchData = function* watchCallFetchData(action: IAction): IterableIterator<any> {
    console.log('calling watchCallFetchData*');
    yield* takeLatest(AppRedux.Action.FETCH_DATA, callFetchData, action)[Symbol.iterator];
    console.log('exiting watchCallFetchData*');
};

export function* rootSaga(action: IAction): IterableIterator<any> {
    console.log('calling rootSaga*');

    const watcher = yield all([
        fork(watchCallFetchData, action),
    ]);

    console.log('exiting rootSaga*');
}

export default [
    rootSaga,
];
```

My routes.ts file:

```typescript
import { RouterState } from 'react-router';
import { ComponentCallback, errorLoading, loadModule } from 'app/routes';
import AppRedux from 'app/containers/App/reducers';
import { call, put } from 'redux-saga/effects';

path: '/somepath/:id',
async getComponent(nextState: RouterState, cb: ComponentCallback) {
    try {
        const renderRoute = loadModule(cb);
        const [reducer, sagas, component] = await importModules();

        const id = nextState.params.id;
        const name = '';
        const action = {
            id,
            name,
            type: AppRedux.Action.FETCH_DATA,
        };

        console.log('routes.ts pre-put fetch_data');
        const putResult = put(action);
        console.log('routes.ts post-put fetch_data');

        return renderRoute(component);
    } catch (err) {
        errorLoading(cb)(err);
    }
},
```

My app.tsx file:

```typescript
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactRouter from 'react-router';
import { connect, DispatchProp } from 'react-redux';
import AppRedux from 'app/containers/App/reducers';
import { createStructuredSelector } from 'reselect';
import { selectid, selectResponses, selectname } from 'app/containers/App/selectors';
import { ISection } from './data';


export class App extends React.Component<IProps, {}> {
    constructor(props: Readonly<IProps>) {
        super(props);
        console.log('app-constructor');
    }

    public render() {
        console.log('app-render');
        return (<div className="app" />);
    }
}

export default connect<{}, {}, IProps>(
    createStructuredSelector({
        id: selectId(),
        data: selectData(),
        name: selectName(),
    }),
    (dispatch) => ({
        fetchData: (id: string, name: string) => dispatch(AppRedux.fetchData(id, name)),
        dispatch,
    }),
)(App);
```

Here is the output from the `console.log` calls:

```
calling rootSaga*
calling watchCallFetchData*
exiting watchCallFetchData*
exiting rootSaga*
routes.ts pre-put fetch_data
routes.ts post-put fetch_data
app-constructor
app-render
```

**EDIT: Clarification**

What I expect to happen:

1. I expect `put(action)` to dispatch the saga action and for Redux-Saga to actually do something.
2. I expect the function `callFetchData` to be called, and like-wise, for it to call `fetchData`.
3. I expect both of those calls to occur before I see `exiting watchCallFetchData*` in the `console.log`.
4. I expect (at some point) to have an "A-ha!" moment.

What's actually happening:

1. The `rootSaga*` function gets called.
2. The `watchCallFetchData*` gets called twice? (Assumption based on what the `yield` statements are supposed to do).
3. The `rootSaga*` function gets called again. (Assumption based on what the `yield` statements are supposed to do).
4. An "A-ha!" moment continues to elude me.

Comment: For 3, use `put` to dispatch actions if you want the watchers to pick them up.

Comment: I think you need to revise your question. What does the code do, and what do you expect it to do? Are the sagas not being triggered? What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @CoryDanielson by "3", do you mean the 3rd code file? I'm using `put` in my routes.ts..

Comment: The 3 in your list of things at the top of the question. `3. I should use put or call to dispatch an action for the watcher to see.`

Comment: @CoryDanielson updated question.

Comment: How is your rootSaga called/used in your code? Are you running it via applyMiddleware? See the section under "Hello Sagas!" in https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/introduction/BeginnerTutorial.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see 2 issues:

**1. Use `yield` instead of `yield*`:** You should be using `yield` without the `*` (superstar) in:

```
yield* takeLatest(AppRedux.Action.FETCH_DATA,...
```

`yield*` is a spread operator that simply takes all the calls inside
    a subroutine and expands them into the macro-function [yield* docs](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/SequencingSagas.html). It's not used
    with `takeLatest`.

**2. Don't pass `action` as parameter:** The action parameter is passed automatically, so it should just be:

```
yield* takeLatest(AppRedux.Action.FETCH_DATA, callFetchData)
```

As `action` is not passed to **rootSaga()** the argument would be `undefined`. When `takeLatest` will try to automatically pass the `action` parameter to **callFetchData**, it will append it to already existing list of arguments ([see the Notes section in takeLatest docs](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#takelatestpattern-saga-args)) & then **callFetchData** will get the real action as the 2nd parameter, which the function isn't expecting, so it won't get passed.

**A suggestion:** `yield all()` internally runs all calls in parallel, so we should use `call` instead of `fork` inside it:

```
const watcher = yield all([
    call(watchCallFetchData, action),
]);
```

**Difference between `takeLatest()` & `while(take())`:** the `take` in while loop is synchronous and blocking, so it doesn't move to the next line until it sees that a desired action is dispatched. It pauses the whole saga. Whereas, `takeLatest()` forks an asynchronous non-blocking thread to wait for the desired action, & keeps executing the next lines of the saga.

Comment: I tried your changes (removing the `*` and not passing the `action` parameter). It made no difference (even the `console.logs` are the same).  Also, I'm not using `takeEvery`, I'm using `takeLatest` (not sure if that makes a difference with your answer or not).

Comment: ya sorry fixed the typo (`takeEvery`). I think `put` only works inside sagas. Shouldn't **routes.ts** file use  `dispatch` instead of `put`? Do you see the `FETCH_DATA` action dispatched in the Redux Developer Tools (Chrome Extension)?

Comment: I see the string I assigned to `FETCH_DATA` in the Redux Developer Tools. It occurs after `@@router/LOCATION_CHANGE`, but the `console.log` calls in the corresponding functions are never hit.

Comment: you can try rewriting `yield takeLatest...` line as `while(true) { const action = yield take(AppRedux.Action.FETCH_DATA); yield call(callFetchData(action)); }` to see if `takeLatest` isn't working for you.

Comment: ok, switching to that seems to work. why? what's so different about it? (although I did `while (yield take(AppRedux.Action.FETCH_DATA)) {    yield call(callFetchData, action); }` instead because I dislike `while(true)` statements on principle). Also, can you update your answer?

Comment: you cannot access the `action` if you do `while(yield take())`. The only way it would work is if you do `while(true) { const action = yield take(); }`. Try console logging your action. You'll see that it's `undefined`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161637/discussion-between-pete-and-ali-saeed).

Answer (score 0):

The changes suggested by @Ali Saeed look correct to me, but I believe that the main issue is your usage of `put` inside of `routes.ts`.

Put only works inside of a generator (saga) run by redux-saga.

In your routes.ts file

```
const putResult = put(action);
```

That line does nothing. If you look at the return value from that you'll see that it simply returns an object.

You want to do

```
store.dispatch(action);
```

Based on your code, the store does not seem available, so you'll have to update that too.

Comment: I tried `store.dispatch(action);` instead of the `put(action)`. It had no effect. I also tried it with [Ali Saeed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2528761/ali-saeed)'s changes. Still no effect.

Comment: Are you running your rootSaga using `applyMiddleware` when you create your store? https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/introduction/BeginnerTutorial.html

Comment: No. The store is created first. My `rootSaga` gets run by the middleware when my app is selected via routes.

Comment: Can you show that code as well? An issue there could explain why `callFetchData` is not being run.